# Show that the sets are closed and convex

Tags: functional-analysis

We consider the sets $K=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^2 \leq 1 \}, L=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^p \leq 1\}$ where $1 \leq p< +\infty, p \neq 2$ , and let $ z \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Check if the euclidean distance of $z$ from $K$ is attained.

I want to show that $K$ is closed and convex. Then by a theorem, the distance will be attained by a unique point.

I have tried to show that $K$ is closed as follows.

Let $(\overline{x_m})$ be a sequence in $K$ such that $\overline{x_m} \to x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
We will show that $x \in K$.
$\overline{x_m}=(x_{m1}, x_{m2}, \dots, x_{mn}), x=(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$

Then $|x_{mi}-x_i| \leq ||\overline{x_m}-x||_2= \left( \sum_{j=1}^n |x_{mj}-x_j|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \to 0$.

Thus $x_{mi} \to x_i$ while $m \to +\infty$ for all $i=1, \dots, n$ with $\sum_{j=1}^n |x_{mj}|^2 \leq 1$ for all $m=1,2, \dots$

Thus $\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^2 \leq 1$ and so $\overline{x} \in K$.

In order to show that $K$ is convex , I have thought the following:

Let $x,y \in K, 0<\lambda<1$.
We will show that $(1- \lambda)x+ \lambda y \in K$.

We have $x=(x_1, \dots, x_n), y=(y_1, \dots, y_n)$ and so $(1- \lambda)x+ \lambda y=((1- \lambda)x_1+ \lambda y_1, \dots, (1-\lambda)x_n+ \lambda y_n )$

So it suffices to show that $\sum_{j=1}^n |(1- \lambda) x_j+ \lambda y_j|^2 \leq 1$.

$ |(1- \lambda) x_j+ \lambda y_j| \leq (1- \lambda) |x_j|+ \lambda |y_j|$

So  $\sum_{j=1}^n |(1- \lambda) x_j+ \lambda y_j|^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n  \left(  (1- \lambda) |x_j|+ \lambda |y_j|\right)^2= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( (1- \lambda)^2 |x_j|^2+ 2 \lambda (1- \lambda) |x_j| |y_j|+\lambda^2 |y_j|^2\right)= (1- \lambda)^2 \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^2 + 2 \lambda (1- \lambda) \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j||y_j| + \lambda^2 \sum_{j=1}^n |y_j|^2$

What bound can we use for  $\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j||y_j| $ to show that the above is $\leq 1$ ?

$$$$

In the same way, we show that $L$ is closed.

In order to show that it is convex we need to show that $\sum_{j=1}^n |(1- \lambda)x_j+ \lambda y_j|^p \leq 1$.

How can we do this?

**EDIT**:

Suppose that we consider the set $K_2:=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^p \leq 1 \}$ where $0<p<1$.

In this case the set isn't convex.

How can we check if the (euclidean) distance of $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ from $K$ is attained?

Comment: Use the convexity of $f(x) = x^p, p \geq 1$

Comment: @RandomJack How can I use it? $$$$
Also do you mean the property which I want to show, this from the last lines?

Comment: $|(1 - \lambda)x_j + \lambda y_j|^p \leq (1-\lambda)|x_j|^p + \lambda |y_j|^p$, so you can bound the sum from the last line by two sums. After that you should use the fact that $x, y \in L$.

Comment: @RandomJack Could you explain me why the inequality holds? $$$$

Then we have $\sum_{j=1}^n |(1- \lambda) x_j+ \lambda y_j|^p \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \left( (1- \lambda) |x_j|^p+ \lambda |y_j|^p \right)=(1- \lambda) \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^p + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^n |y_j|^p \leq 1-\lambda+ \lambda=1$, right?

Comment: The convexity follows directly by using the triangle inequality and the absolute homogeneity of the $p$-norm $\|\cdot\|_p$. Similarly the closedness can be directly show from the continuity of $\|\cdot\|$ (because all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

For the bound of $\sum \mid x_j y_j\mid$, consider

$$
\sum (\mid x_j\mid - \mid y_j\mid)^2=\sum \mid x_j
\mid^2+\sum \mid y_j\mid^2-2\sum \mid x_j y_j\mid\geq 0\implies 1\geq \sum \mid x_j y_j\mid
$$

Comment: So then we have $ \sum_{j=1}^n |(1- \lambda )x_j+ \lambda y_j|^2=((1- \lambda)^2+ \lambda (1- \lambda)) \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^2+ (\lambda (1- \lambda)+ \lambda^2) \sum_{j=1}^n |y_j|^2- \lambda (1- \lambda) \sum_{j=1}^n (|x_j|-|y_j|)^2 \leq (1- \lambda) \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^2 + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^n |y_j|^2 \leq 1$. $$$$
Right? Or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To bound the sum $\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j||y_j|$, use the inequality $2ab \leqslant a^2 + b^2$ with $a = |x_j|$ and $b = |y_j|$.

To prove the convexity of $L$, use the following inequality:
$$|(1 - \lambda)x_j + \lambda y_j|^p \leq (1-\lambda)|x_j|^p + \lambda |y_j|^p$$
which just states that $f(x) = |x|^p$ is a convex function. The proof of this fact depends on what do you know about convex functions. For example, see the standard proof from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535825/show-that-fx-xp-p-ge-1-is-convex-function-on-mathbbrn) question that uses derivatives.

Alternatively, as suggested by Jendrik Stelzner, if you're familiar with the notion of the $p$-*norm* $\|\cdot\|_p$, the convexity of $L$ can be shown as follows. Note that $L = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon \|x\|_p \leq 1\}$ is a *unit ball* in $\mathbb{R}^n$ w.r.t. $p$-norm. Fix some $x, y \in L$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. And consider $z = (1-\lambda)x + \lambda y$. From the trinalge inequality and the absolute homogenity for $p$-norm it follows:
$$\|z\|_p \leq \|(1-\lambda)x\|_p + \|\lambda y\|_p \leq |1-\lambda|\|x\|_p + |\lambda| \|y\|_p = 1 - \lambda + \lambda = 1,$$
where in the first inequality we use the triangle inequality and in the second we use the absolute homogenity of $\|\cdot\|_p$.

Comment: Could you explain to me further how   using the triangle inequality and the absolute homogeneity of the p-norm, we get $|(1- \lambda) x_j+ \lambda y_j|^p \leq (1- \lambda ) |x_j|^p+ \lambda |y_j|^p$ ?

Comment: Well, I'm not using these properties here, I'm just using the convexity of a function $f(x) = |x|^p$ which gives by defintion the desired inequality. A function $f(x) \colon [0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is called *convex* if for all $x, y \in [0, +\infty)$ and any $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ we have $f((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y) \leq (1-\lambda)f(x) + \lambda f(y)$. The convexity of $|x|^p$ is demonstrated in the question I've refered to.

Comment: Is it known that $|x|^p$ is convex? In our case don't we have to prove it?

Comment: @Evinda: I've added alternative proof, suggested by Jendrik Stelzner. It is known that $|x|^p$ is convex (you can see the proof in the question I've referred to in my answer. It uses some facts from analysis, so it is completely up to you whether you need to prove it or not.

Comment: I read now the  proof from this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535825/show-that-fx-xp-p-ge-1-is-convex-function-on-mathbbrn $$$$
Why do we look at $h(g(x))$ and not at $g(h(x))$ ?

Comment: @Evinda: Since you first take the absolute value $|x|$ (or more generally the norm) of $x$ and after that raising it to the $p$th power obtaining $|x|^p$. This is because in general ($p \geq 1$) the function $x \mapsto x^p$ is defined only for $x \in [0, +\infty)$.

Comment: Ok, I will think about it. According to my notes, if $p<1$ the set that we take isn't convex. $$$$
In order to show this, do we have to take $x,y \in K=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^p \leq 1 \}$ and $0 < \lambda <1$ and show that there is no $z \in K$ such that $(1- \lambda)x+ \lambda y=z$ ?

Comment: @Evinda: Yes. Consider, for example, $x = (1, 0,\dots, 0), y = (0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)$ and $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Then $\frac{1}{2} x+ \frac{1}{2} y=\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 0, \dots, 0\right)$. Why doesn't this belong to $K$ ?

Comment: @Evinda: Since $\frac{1}{2^p} + \frac{1}{2^p} = \frac{2}{2^p} = 2^{1-p} > 1$ when $p < 1$.

Comment: @Evinda: Is there still something unclear about your problem? May be I can help?

Comment: In this case when $p<1$ the set is not  convex and so we can't use the fact that if $K$ is closed and convex the distance from $K$ to $ \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is attained. How else can we check if the distance of $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ from $K:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^p \leq 1\}$ where $0<p<1$,  is attained?

Comment: @Evinda: It is better to ask it as a new question.

Comment: I did: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630393/is-the-distance-attained